# How to send Jenkins build notification to MS Teams

Tags: jenkins, groovy, devops, pipeline, microsoft-teams

I have written a Jenkins pipeline job to build and push images, and wanted to get the build notification with `build details`, `tags`, and `committers` in MS-Teams; but I am not able to send notification to the MS-Teams.

Below is what I have tried:

```
stage('MSTEAMS') {     
            steps {
                office365ConnectorSend webhookUrl: "https://orosoft.webhook.office.com/webhookb////xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                message: "The Build has been completed, here is the image URL>>> 123456.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/${REPO}:${TAG}",
                status: "Success",
                color: "00ff00"
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can use an Incoming Webhook to let external applications share content in Microsoft Teams channels. Please check these doc related to [Creating Incoming webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook) , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL